# How to determine CPU and memory cost of a function?

Tags: python, memory-management, cpu-usage

Can someone suggest what would be the best practice or a suitable library to determine:

1. Number of **CPU cycles** used during execution of a Python function?
2. Amount of **Memory** used by the same Python function?

I had looked at **guppy** and **meliae**, but still can't get granular to the function level? Am I missing something?

**UPDATE**
The need for asking this question is to solve a specific situation which is, the scenario is that we have a set of distributed tasks running on cloud instances, and now we need to reorganize the placement of tasks on right instance types withing the cluster, for example high memory consuming functional tasks would be placed on larger memory instances and so on. When I mean tasks (celery-tasks), these are nothing but plain functions for which we need to now profile their execution usage.

Thanks.

Comment: "Am I missing something ?"  Yes.  You're missing the fact that Python rests on one of many implementations: CPython, Jython, PyPy, each of which is different. Most implementations directly or indirectly rest on GNU C libraries which vary from release to release.  It's going to be very, very hard to measure CPU cycles because there are so many layers of software involved.  What are you trying to learn?  What do you need to know?  What decision are you trying to make?

Comment: as @S.Lott said, It will be hard to determine the CPU cycles of the EXACT function since even if you can measure it, the results wont be accurate.

Comment: @S.Lott I do understand the complexity, the scenario is that we have a set of distributed tasks running on cloud instances, and now we need to reorganize the placement of tasks on right instance type, for example high memory consuming functional tasks would be placed on larger memory instances and so on. Hope this explains the need for quest. Thanks.

Comment: @MohammedKhan: Please explain your **actual** problem in the question.  Not in a comment.  Please **update** the question to explain what you're goal is so that we can help.

Comment: @MohammedKhan if your question is about working in the cloud then I think (as @S.Lott says) you need to add quite a bit more information. It may well be that the information you are looking for is more easily obtained from the cloud API than the Python libs. For example, what can be logged in your environment? Can you use the cloud API to log the time that a function starts / stops, which instance it is running on, how much space it is taking up? Can you run `top` on each instance and monitor Python processes from there? etc. etc.

Comment: "still can't get granular to the function level"?  What does this mean?  Why can't you run one function a few times to get a reasonable estimate of CPU time and memory usage?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may want to look into a `CPU profiler` for Python:
http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html

Example output of `cProfile.run(command[, filename])`

```
  2706 function calls (2004 primitive calls) in 4.504 CPU seconds

Ordered by: standard name

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     2    0.006    0.003    0.953    0.477 pobject.py:75(save_objects)
  43/3    0.533    0.012    0.749    0.250 pobject.py:99(evaluate)
...
```

Also, `memory` needs a profiler too:
open source profilers: [PySizer](http://pysizer.8325.org/) and [Heapy](http://guppy-pe.sourceforge.net/#Heapy)

Comment: Thanks @Ayoubi for the above pointer, it surely does help a bit. Thanks again.

Comment: @ayoubi: This displays the execution time, but what about the CPU cycles(CPU utilization), Memory (memory usage) ?